# Attaching a database in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to attach one database to another so that data from it can be used in queries.

I'm using

```
ATTACH DATABASE '{full url}' AS {database_name};
```

No errors actually occur, but when I run

```
PRAGMA database_list
```

Only the main database shows.

Comment: What is the value of `full url` ? SQLite only supports local filenames, not `https://` or anything other.

Comment: @Corion It's just a c:\ address, same drive as the database I'm trying to attach it to.

Comment: @Corion The actual file url contains sensitive information (client references) which I don't want to write out on a public forum. Are the actual letters I use likely to be the problem? They're all normal English letters, no spaces, apostrophes, or weird symbols. Notwithstanding that, is the list of possible issues with a url really so large that it can't simply be written as a few bullet points?

Comment: Well, maybe you're not using an absolute path, then the current directory could matter. Or the filename has an apostrophe in it (like `O'Harris`), which could throw off the syntax. You could try with a sanitized name and see whether things fail there too, and then show that sanitized name instead. But it seems you're more interested in discussing potential ways than finding a solution to your problem. Good luck.

Comment: @Corion I've already said the filename has no apostrophes or spaces and is made entirely from English alphabet letters. I've already said it is an absolute reference to the same drive as the parent database. The reference is cut and pasted from the child database information page (in my gui) so there are no spelling or syntax errors. It doesn't seem like too difficult a question to ask; is there anything else it could be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found these limitations for `ATTACH DATABASE` that may or may not apply to your case:

1. The database names called `main` and `temp` are reserved names within your database connection and can not be used for attached databases.
2. The database name called `main` is reserved for the primary database and the database name called `temp` is reserved for the database that holds temporary tables.
3. Attached databases **must use the same text encoding** as the main database.
4. When the database connection is closed, the attached database will be automatically be detached.

Comment: Thanks, but none of these seem to be the problem either. The other database is not called 'temp' or 'main', they are both UTF-8 according to the pragma encoding, and the database is never attached, so becoming detached doesn't seem to be the problem (unless it is doing so instantaneously for some reason). Any further help with ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've marked this as the answer because even though I can't resolve why, I think the last option is the problem. I've tried three sqlite guis and the third one attached the databases without any trouble using exactly the same command. The first two still will not do so. So I'm guessing it must be something to do with the way the gui software keeps databases connected?

Comment: @Isaacson my guess was that could be the 3d, that's why I emphasized this case, but since you solved your problem everything is fine.